# PHP-CLI not found

Tags: php

After I tried for hours to find the good path for PHP-CLI, i finally found it. But my proud was soon gone again.

Still i got the following error:

The following requirements were not met. As a result video uploads have been disabled.

- Unable to locate path to PHP-CLI

I have tried much different paths

- bin/php
- usr/local/lib
- usr/local/lib/php
- usr/local/bin/php (this is the good one I thought).

Still getting the same error as above. Whats happening? My server is not running in Safe Mode and my `exec()` are enabled via the php.ini file.

Please help me..

**Edit:**

*Paul*

> Q: Have you tried any "fully qualified paths", e.g. "/bin/php" (not
>   just "bin/php")?

A: I have tried both solutions, no result.

> Q: Are you sure php-cli is installed on your system (it's typically a
>   seperate package from the Apache PHP plug-in)? EXAMPLE: apt-get
>   install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli.

A: I tried this in the SSH of my server, its a CentOS server so he didn't found the comment

*@Peter:*

> If you installed PHP through your OS package manager, the path would
>   probably be /usr/bin/php, which appears to be the only one you didn't
>   try

I tried that one now, i didn't help, still the same error:

[image: PHP Cli Error]

**Edit2**

*@Dev-null*

> You have found and what? Just knowing where >is located will not fix it, have you changed some >code or environment variable PATH to make it

A: its an input field where i need to put the path in. I haven't changed any code, because PHP version 5.3.17 (CLI) installed on my CentOS server. So no need to change some code just for the path, right?

**Edit**

My PHP info, PHP 5.3.17 (CLI) Check the image below..

[image: PHP Info]

**Edit**

When I do `rpm -q php-cli` I get `PHP-CLI not installed` and when I want to install i get `No package php-cli available`. See image below.

[image: PHP CLI 2]

**Edit**

Result of `/bin/php -v` below.

[image: PHP CLI -v Result]

Comment: Q: Have you tried any "fully qualified paths", e.g. "/bin/php" (not just "bin/php")?  Q: Are you sure php-cli is installed on your system (it's typically a *seperate* package from the Apache PHP plug-in)?  EXAMPLE: `apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli`.

Comment: If you installed PHP through your OS package manager, the path would probably be `/usr/bin/php`, which appears to be the only one you didn't try.

Comment: You have found and what? Just knowing where is located will not fix it, have you changed some code or environment variable `PATH` to make it work?

Comment: Is PHP-CLI installed? Instead of `apt-get` as on debian/ubuntu, you'd use `yum` for this: `sudo yum install php php-cli`.

Comment: If you run "which php" what do you get in return?

Comment: @Deleteman `/usr/bin/which: no php-cli in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/b‌​in)`

Comment: Since it is CentOS one more standard question: is selinux enabled on your server? Apache/other webserver process runs with lower privileges and can have denied access to php executables.

Answer (score 6):

CentOS ships the PHP command-line interpreter in the `php-cli` package. So you first need to verify whether it's installed or not:

```
rpm -q php-cli
```

If installed, you can list all its files:

```
rpm -ql php-cli
```

... and filter out potential binaries:

```
rpm -ql php-cli | grep /bin/
```

You can get further details in the [Using RPM](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html) chapter of the deployment guide.

If the package is not installed:

```
yum install php-cli
```

More info at [Installing New Software with yum](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html#sn-yum-installing-withrepositories).

---

*All this answer assumes that nobody broke the package system by installing software manually. If that happened, there's no way to tell what changes were made to the system.*

**Edit #1:** I've just seen your last edit where php-cli is up and running. Then, if you want to know the path you just need to type this:

```
which php
```

**Edit #2:** You seem to have up to 4 binaries called `php` in your path. I still think that the proper reliable way to find the `php-cli` binary is running `rpm -ql php-cli` but given that `php` finds it on the path I'm pretty sure that it's located at `/bin/php` and you can verify it by running:

```
/bin/php -v
```

Run that exact command—don't remove any slashes or append `-cli`.

If your script, whatever it looks like, cannot find it, it's either doing it wrong or it's missing the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. When I use `which PHP` Then i get the following paths:

`bin/php`
`usr/local/lib`
`usr/local/lib/php`
`usr/local/bin/php`

None of this is the good one.. still get the same error as above..

Comment: G. Victoria. No with the leading slashes, but still not working when i put it in the field of my script.

Comment: The leading slashes are _very_ important.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario See image above for the result of `/bin/php -v`

Answer (score 1):

try the following to find it:

```
sudo find / -name php-cli
```

You most likely want php instead of php-cli though.

Comment: Will the correct path of PHP-CLI show up with this command? Im going to try and let you know if this is the solution.

Comment: @DennisStrooband You can also try `which php-cli`, which should show the path to the executable that the OS thinks is correct for the command `php-cli`, though will return an empty result if it doesn't recognize the command. Try `which ls` to see an example of something that works.

Comment: @Natahlien when i put this command I get this response: `/usr/bin/which: no php-cli in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have it installed.

Comment: @Jonatan I have added a image on from my PHP info in my question post. Please take a look for me, you see PHP 5.3.17 (CLI). So its installed right?

Comment: What you posted there is the output of the `php` command, not `php-cli` - maybe you want to invoke `php -a`? See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions on this page found the installed versions of PHP that were present in my own elusive search for php-cli. The solution for me was to use the following command:

```
locate bin/php
```

This listed all php versions and I could then replace `php` with, for example:

```
/usr/bin/php71-cli
```

To access the command line interface version of php rather than the default cgi one. I then alias my instructions like so:

```
alias composer='/usr/bin/php71-cli bin/composer.phar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed "drush" for my drupal website.
when I tried to run "drush":

```
[root@server /]# drush

/usr/share/drush/drush.launcher: line 132: /usr/bin/php-cli: No such file or directory

[root@server /]#
```

php-cli was not in my default directory /usr/bin

Solution was to copy my "php"-file to "php-cli" file (no rename!!, just copy)

```
[root@server /]# cp php php-cli
```

weird, but still working!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please be so kind to edit your answer and apply some formatting. Btw, copying is not the way. You should do a symlink `ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-cli`.